# Source Code Being Displayed on Forward/Back

Tags: javascript, symfony

I'm having an issue that I've never ran into and can't find much information on at all. I'm writing a web application that uses Symfony 2 along with your standard front end technology stack. It looks like in my production environment, whenever the user uses the front and back buttons on their browser, the page source code is displayed.

We have three other environments in which this application lives for testing and development, and even one that is almost identical to production. It's pretty much as close as humanly possible without actually being it. But, for some reason, the issue only shows up on production so it has been very difficult to test. We use a few analytic and tracking scripts in which I thought may be the issue but after disabling them and pushing to production, the issue still exists.

I had the feeling that this may be Javascript related so I disabled JS in my browser and poof, no more problem. Now my questions is, what are situations with Javascript that could lead to something like this occurring? Has anyone ever experienced a similar situation? We use a lot of JS and I've been trying to just pull stuff out but we use a lot of JS and have to re-deploy every time.

Comment: Does your symfony2 server render a view ? Maybe you are displaying a layout and after make your own templating and routing using your frontend stack. If it does, you could have a mistake in your response.

Comment: Just in case people were wondering this, the problem was one of our analytics libraries. It was only running in production for tracking purposes, which is why we could only see it there. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case people were wondering this, the problem was one of our analytics libraries. It was only running in production for tracking purposes, which is why we could only see it there. Made a few adjustments with the way we were using our analytics and resolved the problem.